# Incorrect NSStringEncoding Value

Tags: objective-c, xcode8

I'm getting this message during run in Xcode 8.

`Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x8000100 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.`

How can I track this down? I cannot find `0x8000100` anywhere in my project.

Answer (score 9):

The incorrect encoding value -- `0x8000100` -- is in `kCFStringEncodingUTF8` which is defined on `CFString.h`.

In my code I had this line:

`[NSString stringWithCString:cString encoding:kCFStringEncodingUTF8];`

which caused the error. Instead use this from now on:

`[NSString stringWithCString:cString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: On the odd change you come here because you are getting this log message in response to using NSAttributedString dataFromRange documentAttributes to produce an NSHTMLTextDocumentType, you can fix it by adding NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding) to the attributes past in to the method.